# proving that a function is well defined

Tags: functional-analysis

Please, can someone help me? I have the following problem:
Let $X$ be a normed space, $Y \subset X$ a linear subspace of $X$ and the function $$d_{Y}(x)=inf\{||x-y||:y \in Y\}$$;I have to prove that $N:X/Y \to \mathbb{R}$, $N(\overline{a})= d_{Y}(a)$ is well defined. I picked $\overline{a}, \overline{b}$ from $X/Y$, with $\overline{a}=\overline{b} $. I have to show that $N(\overline{a})=N(\overline{b})$. I have that $a−b \in Y$; $N(\overline{a})=d_{Y}(a)=inf\{||b+y′−y||:y∈Y\}$ ; $N(\overline{b})=inf\{||b−y||: y \in Y\}$ (where $a=b+y', y' \in Y$). We have that the map $f:Y \to Y$, by $f(y)=y−y′$, with $y′$ a fixed element in $Y$ is a bijection.  So as $y$ "walks" in the set $Y$ and covers it entirely, so it will do $y-y'$; so that sets are equal, so their inf-s are equal..Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea as a whole is correct. If you are not convinced with the equality of the two infimums, you can do as follows:

For $y \in Y$, we have
$$y - y' \in Y \implies \|b - (y - y')\| \geq \inf \{ \|b - \tilde{y}\|: \tilde{y} \in Y\} = N(\bar{b}).$$
Taking infimum over $y \in Y$ we have
$$N(\bar{a}) = \inf \{\|b - (y - y')\|: y \in Y\} \geq N(\bar{b}).$$

Similarly, for $y \in Y$, we have
$$y + y' \in Y \implies \|b - y\| = \|(b + y') - (y + y')\| \geq \inf \{ \|(b + y') - \tilde{y}\|: \tilde{y} \in Y\} = N(\bar{a}).$$
Taking infimum over $y \in Y$ we have
$$N(\bar{b}) = \inf \{\|b - y\|: y \in Y\} \geq N(\bar{a}).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$d_Y(a) = \inf\{\|a-y\|:y\in Y\} = \inf\{\|a-(a-b+y)\|:(a-b+y)\in Y\}= $$
$$=\inf\{\|b-y\|:y\in Y \}= d_Y(b)$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x,z$ are equivalent in $X/Y$ then $z = x+y$. Consider the following: If $y' \in Y$ is $d$ far from $x$, i.e. $|| x - y'|| = d$, then $y'+y$ is $d$ far from $x+y = z$. The rest follows from the definition of infimum.